# debugging my iPad App crash on adding a entry to the calendar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, crash

I am developing a iPad app. My app has a feature where there is a button from where I can add the calendar entry to it. However when I am done adding the entry, the App crashes :( However whenever I open the App next time I see the entry was made successfully though. Any pointers on how this issue could be fixed ?

Comment: Source code and console output would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are possibly releasing something that you dont own or trying to use something after it has been released.

If you run your app with the debugger on, you will be able to trace the exact line where the crash is occuring as you can see the stack when it crashes.

And yes, output from the console will help when you ask this sort of question.

Comment: I ran with the debugger on but it not show anything happening. I might be missing something here. It would be great if you could guide me more here. Been stuck in this problem since yesterday :(

Comment: What do mean when you say you ran with the debugger on? If you look to the right of the baby debug controls when the crash occurs you might see obj_msg_send or SIG_KILL . Click on that and you get a stack trace. Or use the full debug window

Comment: Warren, I used the zombie instrument and fixed the problem. I was sending something to a object which was already deallocated.